# Restrict function args types based on other args type in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have got a function that has 4 parameters - `body`, `id`, `size`, and `variation`.

Based on these `variation` types I want to change the `size` types in the typescript.
eg:

```
const Title: FC<TitleProps> = ({body, id, size, variation}) => {
    ...
}

export interface TitleProps {
  body: string;
  id: string;
  size: 's' | 'm' | 'l';
  variation: 'title' | 'subtitle'
}
```

In the above interface, I want the size types to be changed according to the variation

```
variation: 'title'
size: 's' | 'm' | 'l'

variation: 'subtitle'
size: 'xl' | 'l' | 'm'
```

Comment: I don't know if this really depends on react; if not, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZ1VEN) might meet your needs?  Let me know if you want to see that as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz, yes the above solution worked perfectly fine, although I was expecting the storybook to pick up these types and add them to controls that's okay. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work you need to use a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of object types, where one union member represents the `"title"` variation and the other represents the `"subtitle"` variation.  Here's one way to do it:

```
interface BaseTitleProps {
    body: string;
    id: string;
}

interface TitleProps extends BaseTitleProps {
    size: 's' | 'm' | 'l';
    variation: 'title'
}

interface SubtitleProps extends BaseTitleProps {
    size: 'm' | 'l' | 'xl';
    variation: 'subtitle'
}

type SomeTitleProps = TitleProps | SubtitleProps
```

Here, `BaseTitleProps` has the properties common to all interfaces, while `TitleProps` and `SubtitleProps` extend them in two different ways to represent your requirements.  And then `SomeTitleProps` is the union of `TitleProps` and `SubtitleProps`.

Now you can use `SomeTitleProps` as your function input and the compiler will treat it as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where checking the `variation` property will narrow the apparent type of the `size` property.  Indeed you can even [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the properties into separate variables and the compiler [will still treat those variables as if they were discriminated union properties](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions):

```
const Title: (x: SomeTitleProps) => JSX.Element = ({ body, id, size, variation }) => {
    if (variation === "title") {
        size // (parameter) size: "s" | "m" | "l"
    } else {
        size // (parameter) size: "m" | "l" | "xl"
    }
    return null! // impl here
}
```

And when you call `Title` you are only allowed to do so with valid attributes:

```
 <Title body="abc" id="def" variation="title" size="s"></Title> // okay
 <Title body="abc" id="def" variation="subtitle" size="xl"></Title> // okay
 <Title body="abc" id="def" variation="subtitle" size="s"></Title> // error, 
 // Types of property 'size' are incompatible.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=7&ts=4.9.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgCEUBnJAFWBgBskABRxh2cAN7k40uACMIAEwCeALjjsYUGgHMKMuMAVqNW6rvIBfKrXqM0zHvyEixSAB51qCsW06OBwhCiElIy7MAAXkhq+Oz4cAA+BCDxSfh8ZKHSAG4oWigwwBDUMYVO+JbWdAxMcADKAK6yZQEucO6e3qwc3LytQWKS+uFRMSmJBBkT+G4ZejK5+YXFMexNLUgVVjBKYMx1uL1OgcEAvHD+zgMTjc19V6KU5GjFGhf3agAUbmoHIEf9UQASjgpwAfHAAFJ1AAaADoAKICf60UFwT7iOSKJQAGgMCjxIyQeMWwAKRWocAsIPBIX0wEw6NJ5OKoNO5wARBsOSChvowpFmAB6IXosB5FD-aogolqDnsDkTDkgRVJDl8DlZKntPicOn86REuAisUSqX0GWCuUqpUapWzTX6Kz6IgwBpQSnUBp8PgAQmNotAYD4cAAFvQkJVyAAeBTAbJgrXRy5Y5SnDkoWRoRWGdMKJCYRXM5bUdPc9SC9MKsHRoWXCEmiAAaxQSiTKfkaYzWZzCjzBaLeTJJar63uiqJ6YdNbr9wboubrfb91TSnTmez+P7hbgxYpo7uTgnlflHJn9YD7SgOCgeK1Jq4uyQYggjLAInoOwIRPieWYNBecByVkAQ4RjIU4wTIA)

Comment: there is 1 more issue. The size props when hovered show ('s' | 'm' | 'l' | 'xl') in Title component. Once I use this Title component as reusable component, I will be passing size and variation as props to Title component, which creates an issue cuz size types passed right now is ('s' | 'm' | 'l' | 'xl') and in the parent component I have used union to separate the types but it still shows the error that " Type 's' | 'm' | 'l' | 'xl' is not assignable to 's' | 'm' | 'l' | undefined ".

Comment: That sounds like a followup question where you've run into the bug described at [ms/TS#27211](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27211).  I hope the answer to this question doesn't depend on that being cleared up.